# Divide single Value for a many in table C#

Tags: c#, arrays, divide

From

```
int BinaryTable = new int[] { 1101 };
```

To

```
int BinaryTable = new int[] { 1,1,0,1 };
```

Don't know how to change it right.

Comment: `int[] BinaryTable`?

Comment: I have to count from Binary value to Decimal.

Comment: You need to give us more information. Your question does not contain enough information about what you are trying to do. Please edit your question to help explain what you are attempting to do and the steps you have done to try to solve this problem yourself. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `1101` binary is `13`; you want 13 integer convert to `[1, 1, 0, 1]` array?

Comment: I want to convert from sample Binary value to Decimal value in array;

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
var bits = BinaryTable.Select(b => 
                 b.ToString().
                 Select(r => r == '0'  ? 0 : 1))
              .SelectMany(x => x);
```

This works if you want to get from

> [1101,11] → [1,1,0,1,1,1]

. It is not really clear what exact do you want. And this solution doesn't check that your input really contains only 1 and 0 digits, since it is integer it could theoretically contain every number.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] BinaryTable = new int[] { 1101 };
List<int[]> allItems = new List<int[]>();
foreach (var item in BinaryTable)
{
    var items = item.ToString().Select(y => int.Parse(y.ToString())).ToArray();
    allItems.Add(items);
}

var final = allItems.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx):

```
 int value = 1101; // a bit strange representation 

 int[] BinaryTable = value
   .ToString()
   .Select(c => c - '0')
   .ToArray();
```

Or since `13 == 1101 binary`:

```
  int value = 13; // just an integer

  int[] BinaryTable = Convert.ToString(value, 2)
    .Select(c => c - '0')
    .ToArray();
```

In case you want convert one *array* into another *array*, use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`:

```
  int[] source = new int[] {1101};

  int[] BinaryTable = source
    .SelectMany(value => value.ToString()
      .Select(c => c - '0')) 
    .ToArray();
```

Or
      int[] source = new int[] {13};

```
  int[] BinaryTable = source
    .SelectMany(value => Convert
       .ToString(value, 2)
       .Select(c => c - '0')) 
    .ToArray();
```